# Getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out when making Jira Server Search Rest API call

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, timeoutexception, socket-timeout-exception

I am making following Jira Issue Search Rest API call to fetch all the issues in a project having 1 or more issuelinks from my Jira instance and I am using pagination for collecting all issues from a project using startAt index query Param

**{Jira_Instance_URL}/rest/api/2/search?jql=project={ProjectKey} AND issueFunction in hasLinks()&fields=issuelinks&startAt=0&maxResults=-1**

My Jira instance is having huge number of issues. When I am getting into a project "XYZ". It is having around 30,000 issues and I am looping over after getting 1000 issues at a time.

**The Jira Issue Search Rest API is giving following exception after lopping over around 20,000 issues:**

2022-11-10 13:23:41 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] ERROR JiraIFAppender - Error occured while fetching issues keys and issuelink ids for XYZ due to I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/search": Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Because of which I am not able to fetch all the issues in that particular project.

Can anyone please guide on how to resolve the above exception.

Thanks & Regards,

Preethi H R

Comment: You need to try to increase the timeout of the socker connection.

Comment: Hi, current timeout is set to 5min. I have also tried with 10 minutes but still it is failing.

Comment: Then in this case, it might be the server killing the connection.  I suggest you use pagination if available